# Aptana Studio 3.0.4 64bit can't remember FTP password

Tags: ftp, passwords, aptana, remember-me

I have a problem with remember FTP password in new aptana studio 3.0.4
Only after new install it, I find the FTP password cannot be remembed.

Does anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can try deleting and re-creating your secure storage settings...please see here for more information: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Miscellaneous